# sticky support on chrome for table-row div

Tags: css, sticky

I have a page that already has a menu that is sticky.  I have a div table with a header table-row that I need to also be sticky.

I added the portion:stick and it works fine in other browsers, but not chrome (I have v76).

The Div table is like this:

```
<div class="Table" >
    <div class="Heading" id="headliner">
        <div class="Cell"> <p>#</p></div>
        <div class="Cell"> <p>Name (id), Email, Phone</p></div>
        <div class="Cell" style="width:150px;"> <p>Member since</p></div>
...
    </div>
</div>
```

The CCS style for the table row is

```
.Heading  {
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:white;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    top:48px;
    }
```

Why is the sticky on a table-row div not working in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the non-vendor-prefixed rule

```css
position: sticky;
```

which is what Chrome will be looking for; see http://www.chromium.org/blink/developer-faq#TOC-Will-we-see-a--chrome--vendor-prefix-now- and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/position-sticky

Comment: Added that and it still does not work.  Is it possible to have two sticky items?